# How to unit test Stream.reduce Method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, java-stream

I need to unit test `reduce()` method. Not sure why it is throwing `NullPointerException`, though I can see the object is not null.

Please refer the below code.

```
  Mock:-
  when(mergeUtility.mergeJson(josnObj1, jsonObj2)).thenReturn( new
  JsonParser().parse(MergeConstant.mergedJsonObject).getAsJsonObject());
```

Actual method:

```
Optional<JsonObject> aggregatedJson = 
     jsonList.stream().reduce(mergeUtility :: mergeJson);
```

When I am testing `jsonList` has to objects, still `NullPointerException` is getting thrown from `reduce()` method. Could someone please let me know the reason?

Comment: try putting mergeUtility.mergeJson(Mockito.any(),Mockito.any()) when you  are mocking.

Comment: @Yasham it worked. Could you please explain reason behind it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below :-

```
 when(mergeUtility.mergeJson(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn( new
  JsonParser().parse(MergeConstant.mergedJsonObject).getAsJsonObject());
```

The reason behind it is though you are mocking the method but you are sending the 
parameters as `josnObj1, jsonObj2` which are different than the objects generated by jsonList while executing your test case, so when you do an equals operation on the items generated by the list and the `josnObj1, jsonObj2` they won't match.As the objects are not matching the method call does not match to the one you have mocked hence mocking is not performed.

Whereas when you use `Mockito.any()` it will mock the method irrespective of the parameter which is given to the method even though they don't match.